# document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0]["__proto__"] instanceof HTMLUListElement is false

Tags: javascript, web-component, polyfills, babel-polyfill, incognito-mode

I have native and web components in my website. And I use document-register-element polyfill. When I check `document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0]["__proto__"] instanceof HTMLUListElement` is returning false.

When I checked what is HTMLUListElement is console log, it returns

```
ƒ (e){var t,n;return(e=e||this)[Q]||(ae=!0,t=ie[le.get(e.constructor)],(e=(n=te&&1===t.create.length)?Reflect.construct(r,Y,t.constructor):d.createElement.apply(d,t.create))[Q]=!0,ae=!1,n||tt(e)),e}
```

And when I checked `document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0]['__proto__']` in console log. It returns

```
HTMLUListElement {Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "HTMLUListElement", constructor:
```

It will help me to fix the issue if I get the answer why HTMLUListElement and my DOM node constructor are different. Any help is appreciated.

And this is happening only first time when I load the page in chrome incognito mode. I couldn't test in other browsers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `(new Array()).constructor instanceof Array` is false too. The constructor is a function, so I don't know what you expect.

Comment: The constructor function is going to be a *function*, not an element type.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I mean document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0]['\__proto__']. It should return what it is returning for HTMLUListElement.

Comment: I'm getting `function HTMLUListElement() { [native code] }`, not some minified something, does that have to do with your register-element polyfill?

Answer (score 1):

This is normal.

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(document.createElement("ul")) === HTMLUListElement.prototype
```

which means that

```
document.createElement("ul") instanceof HTMLUListElement
```

will evaluate to `true`, but

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(document.createElement("ul")) instanceof HTMLUListElement
// i.e.
HTMLUListElement.prototype instanceof HTMLUListElement
```

will be `false` since the object does not inherit from itself.

Comment: Thanks for you are answer. Your logic works for new elements created using document.createElement. But it fails for element that is already rendered.

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0]` should be exactly the same as `document.createElement("ul")` (unless it is `undefined` of course). Can you try without loading that polyfil? It seems to mess with the builtins.